# How to access properties to an object at a specific index in a Viewbag, out of a foreach?

Tags: c#, javascript, list, asp.net-mvc-4, onchange

I have a select input where I display data from a ViewBag which contains a list of objects, "Contacts":

```
<select id="choix_contact" onchange="javascript:RemplirTextbox();">
       <option>Choisir un contact</option>
             @if (ViewBag.ListeContacts != null)
                 {
                      foreach (var Contact in ViewBag.ListeContacts)
                           {
                                 <option>@Contact.Nom</option>
                           }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    <option>Pas de contact</option>  
                 }
```

The thing is that i want to handle the onchange javascript event on the select. When we choose a contact in the list, i would like to fill textboxes with other properties of the contact. The list contains contact with properties as follows:

```
new Contact(nom_contact, prenom_contact, email_contact, formation_contact, telephoneFixe_contact, telephonePortable_contact)
```

For example when we choose a contact named : Hubert, i would that in the textbow below, the number of the contact appears in the textbox with the Id : TelNumber.
I have tried a lot of things, but outside a foreach, i don't know how to access properties of the object. I know that we can get to know the index of the object in the list by doing this:

```
int index = ViewBag.ListeContacts.IndexOf(Contact);
```

Does somebody has an idea ? i don't have any left...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try and avoid getting into the messiness of getting razor variables inline with your javascript.

Also, try to shy away from using ViewBag wherever possible.

I would approach this by having a method on one of your controllers which takes a Contact string as a parameter, and accesses your database and returns a list of the variables you want.

Then, add an event handler in javascript to your value change event of your dropdown box, and fire off an Ajax call to your controller method. This would then access your data storage, and return the values, which would then be fed down to your JS via ajax. You could then populate your textboxes at your leisure.